# Is this the right way to join tables to fetch data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the tables:

```
Student(SID,Name,Surname,Age)
Registration(StudentID,CourseID)
Course(CID,Name,Cost)
```

I would like to extract only the name of the courses with students younger than 20. Will the query below do just that?

```
SELECT C.NAME
FROM Course C
INNER JOIN Registration
INNER JOIN Student S
WHERE CID = CourseID
    AND SID = StudentID
    AND Age < 20
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

I would also like to extract the number of students in each course having students younger than 20. Is it correct to do it as below?

```
SELECT count(S.NAME)
    ,C.NAME
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Course C
INNER JOIN Registration
WHERE Age < 20
    AND CID = CourseID
    AND SID = StudentID
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

Comment: what db are you using? Mysql or SQL? There are sintax difference between the two

Comment: @LelioFaieta Can you give me a link to the `SQL` DB? I'm quite curious how it's different from MySQL.

Comment: @ Lelio - post is tagged with MySQL....

Comment: @LelioFaieta I taught that SQL is just a language while MySQL is a database, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Because you are using different column names in each table, you will probably need to include what columns you are joining the tables on

Comment: @MuppetGrinder post is tagged with SQL also. And Oracle db, as far as I know, use SQL. All the other (mysql, mssql and so on) use derived languages with syntax differences

Comment: You're missing the `on` clause in the joins, you're using them in the `where` clause instead. the result may be the same but if you were to introduce outer joins, you would get wrong results

Comment: @MuppetGrinder You are not obligated to specify the column names if they are all distinct, so no similar column name in two tables.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu  I just wasn't sure if a natural join would associate across two tables where the there wasn't a common column name. I haven't tried joining tables without explicitly defining the on() clause.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. Oracle and all the others have their own versions, some more and some less standard compliant. No dbms product is fully standard compliant.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the info. As far as I know Oracle is the closest one to the standard... am I wrong?

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I'm not sure which one who is the closest. Perhaps DB2 or Postresql aren't that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ON part for the join otherwise it would just be a CROSS JOIN.

Your first query should look like this if you want just a distinct list of student names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.NAME
FROM Course C
INNER JOIN Registration R ON C.CID = R.CourseID
INNER JOIN Student S ON R.StudentID = S.SID
WHERE Age < 20
```

Your second query shouldn't really have the C.Name in the select if you want to get just a count unless you want a count of how many students have that name.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Registration R ON s.SID = R.StudentID
INNER JOIN Course C ON c.CID = R.CourseID
WHERE Age < 20
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

Comment: It's true, the first query won't need a GROUP BY, but I think the OP was actually looking for DISTINCT, since a JOIN with Registration will most likely yield duplicate course names. Thus, I recommend you adjust your answer and include a DISTINCT in the first query.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu ah that is a good point since it is likely a many to many.

Comment: ... an inner join is just a filtered cross join. the queries in the OP provided the required results, just in a slightly oddly written format that mixed implicit and explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

More correctly, you should move the conditions of the join, to the join statements themselves by including them in the `on` clause instead of the `where`.  While the results may not change in this instance, if you were to start including `outer joins` you would encounter difficulties.

```
SELECT count(S.NAME)
    ,C.NAME
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Registration R
  ON s.SID = R.StudentID
INNER JOIN Course C
  ON c.CID = R.CourseID
WHERE Age < 20
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

There's a fiddle here showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3b8f/1

Your first query will also produce the results you want, but again, you should move the join predicates to the join itself.  Also, you don't need to perform the grouping just to get distinct values, mysql has an expression for that called `distinct`. So rewritten, the first query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.NAME
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Registration R
  ON s.SID = R.StudentID
INNER JOIN Course C
  ON c.CID = R.CourseID
WHERE Age < 20.
```

Again, the results are the same as what you have already but it is easier to 'read' and will put you in good stead when you move on to other queries.  As it stands you have mixed implicit and explicit join syntax.

This fiddle demonstrates both queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3b8f/4

**edit**

I may have misinterpreted your original question - if you want the total number of students enrolled in a course with at least one student under 19, you can use a query like this:

```
select name, count(*)
  from course c 
    inner join registration r
      on c.cid = r.courseid
  where exists (
    select 1
      from course cc
        inner join registration r
          on cc.cid = r.courseid
        inner join student s
          on s.sid = r.studentid
      where cc.cid = c.cid
      group by cc.cid
      having min(s.age) < 20
   )
  group by name;
```

Again with the updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3b8f/17

Answer (score 0):

First join these tables, then group by Course's PK(*CID*), Add the `HAVING` condition to filter the course which has students younger than 20.

Then use `Course` table to join the result to get the course name and count of students in the course.

```
SELECT 
  T1.Name, 
  T2.StudentCount 
FROM 
  Course T1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      c.CID, 
      COUNT(s.SID) AS StudentCount
    FROM 
      Course c 
    LEFT JOIN Registration r ON c.CID = r.CourseID 
    LEFT JOIN Student s ON s.SID = r.StudentID 
    GROUP BY c.CID 
    HAVING COUNT(IF(s.Age < 20, 1, NULL)) > 0    
) T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID
```

Comment: now the real question is does the op really mean 'count of all students' in course or 'count of all students under 20' in course

Comment: @pala_ The op said `the number of students in each course having students younger than 20 `, but not `the number of students younger than 20 in each course`, that's the point, isn't that?

Comment: Yes, and all questions here are perfectly worded, right? :)